# Infragistics CodedUI extension for vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, infragistics, coded-ui-tests

Since CodedUI does not support Infragistics winforms by default, a hotfix has to be installed which imports a specific assembly enabling codedUI to work with infragistics controls. [This hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2696646/en-us) works with vs2010 pretty fine, but not actually with vs2012. [Their site](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Coded_UI_Test_Extension_Overview.html#_System_Requirements) says that this hotfix should work with vs2012 but I just can't install this hotfix because of a compatibility issue. When I try to install it, this is the error message I get:

```
KB2696646 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.  Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225649 for more details.
```

Is there a way to get the assembly without installing this hotfix?
Or could someone just share it? This is the one I need: `Infragistics4.Win.CodedUITest.UIA.VS11.v12.2.dl`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at : http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/79850/402667.aspx#402667  for more details. Also there you could find mentioned assembly.

Comment: Great support from the infragistics team. Thanks a lot. I've got one more question: Do I have to buy the full NetAdvantage license to have CodedUI support? I don't need anything but CodedUI from it.

Comment: Yes, it is part of NetAdvantage for Windows Forms.